# Could TCP be used with lower level protocols like for eg Ethernet or SONET

Tags: tcp

Out of curiosity can we implement a TCP stack directly over Ethernet and use that for reliability and flow control on a LAN network.

Comment: TCP is built on top of IP, which tends to be implemented on top of things like ethernet. It's not clear that you're asking for anything that isn't already common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TCP in tightly integrated on IP. One example is its use of a [pseudoheader](http://www.netfor2.com/tcpsum.htm) which incorporates specific parts of the IP header for purposes of checksum calculation. Also, I doubt if any TCP implementations exist which don't contain pervasive assumptions of 32-bit (for IPv4) or 128-bit (for IPv6) addresses.

Why would you want to skip IP and run TCP directly over a lower layer? Just to save 20 bytes of header?